# I am getting ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END in node js api. How to fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting a issue which is given below when i hit the upload file api from ui. I am hitting a node js api from react js and then hit public api from node js.
[image]

> node version:- 10.15.3
>
> npm version:- 6.4.1

#### Api

```
router.route("/uploadLocaleFile").post(function(req, res, next) {
  req.on("data", data => {
    uploadFile(req, data, res);
  });
});

function uploadFile(req, data, res) {
  request
    .post({
      uri: `${notebookPath}/localfile/${req.query.experimentId}`,
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": req.headers["content-type"],
        Authorization: req.headers["authorization"]
      }
    })
    .pipe(res);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
router.route("/uploadLocaleFile").post(function(req, res, next) {
  const chunks = [];
  req
    .on('data', data => chunks.push(data))
    .on("end", _ => uploadFile(req, Buffer.concat(chunks), res)
  ;
});

function uploadFile(req, data, res) {
  request
    .post({
      uri: `${notebookPath}/localfile/${req.query.experimentId}`,
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": req.headers["content-type"],
        Authorization: req.headers["authorization"]
      }
    })
    .pipe(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try @Yaroslav Gaponov solution.

Your problem was that `.pipe(res)` is triggering on each `data` event. By the time your second `data` event occurs, the `res` stream is already closed.

What @Yaroslav Gaponov did, was that, on each `data` event, he stores the incoming buffer into an array. When the stream is done the `end` event will be emited, and only then you are allowed to do 1 write to `res`, that is, the `.pipe(res)` from *uploadFile*.

You can also try `request` one line pipe like so:

> req.pipe(request(your_options)).pipe(res)

Comment: For text file, it is working but json aur js file it gives error.